# Split array into subarray java

Tags: java, split

```
String s = "How are you?"
String[] a = s.split("\\s");
```

giving a = [How,are,you?]

further i want to split array a into sub array H,o,w

```
String[] b = a.split(""); // error here
```

Comment: `a` is a array not `String`, you can't call `split("")` on it

Comment: welcome to SO. Please at least show you put a minimal amount of effort into your post. make use of the edit feature to improve the quality of your question

Comment: which method i should use to split array

Comment: You need to use a loop on array `a`. And split each elements of that array something like: `a[i].split("")`.

Comment: `a` array is already spliced, use `a[i]` to access object inside , or use for each to loop over all object.

Comment: Thank you procastinator & Ebraheem Alrabee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. As mentioned in the comments. `a` is not a string but an array. So you need to iterate over it to call the `split()` method on it's containing strings

```
String s = "How are you?"
String[] a = s.split("\\s");
for(String s2 : a){
    String[] a2 = s2.split("");
    // do your stuff with a2 in every iteration
}
```

Comment: `s2.split("")` works ? I would use `toCharArray()` instead but get a `char[]`

Comment: @AxelH yeah of course but I'm not sure if the example from OP is a real one or just an example

Comment: Note that this was giving a "wrong" result in older version (java 6) gave `[,h,o,w]` but know we do have `[h,o,w]`. Strange ... but nice !

Comment: @AxelH oh really? I didn't know that. glad I'm using `java8` then

Comment: I had to work with some "old" technology ... but this is still used in some company ... unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

try

`"How".toCharArray()` to get each letter or loop through

```
String str = "How";
for (int i = 0;i < str.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also first remove all space chars and split afterwards.

```
    String s = "How are you?";
    String[] a = s.replaceAll("\\s","").split("");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

    //[H, o, w, a, r, e, y, o, u, ?]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get character stream and print each character individually, e.g.:

```
String s = "How are you";
s.chars()
    .forEach(c -> System.out.println((char)c));
```